# Phrase or word for describing a basic pricing rationale?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming

I'm creating an application where customers can buy things. For some things they are charged based on the quantity of things they buy, but for others they are based on the total weight of the things they buy. Is there some specific term, single word or few words, that succintly describes the way in which something will be charged? For example: "`The _____ for this product is the total weight of items.`" or even just "`_____: weight`".

I'm actually still unsure whether this word or term will be used in the user interface, but it will definitely be needed in the API of the application, as in there will be a method named something like `get[TERM_OR_PHRASE]` that will return either "`weight`" or "`quantity`".

**Edit:** For what it's worth, I'm Finnish, and in Finnish the word I'd use is *hinnoitteluperuste*, but no web dictionary seems to find any translation for it.

Comment: 'Sold by weight' is the idiomatic descriptor for the obvious situation. 'Sold by number' is also used, though a little less commonly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Alright, thanks, that would fill my middle slot nicely. But for an API a "`getSoldBy`" (or "`getChargedBy`") still sounds clunky, doesn't it?

Comment: No less clunky than `getHinnoitteluperuste`, I think! Is that a compound word? If so, could you provide a literal translation of each constituent part?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, sure, it's [hinnoittelu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hinnoittelu) + [peruste](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peruste), where "hinnoittelu" = "act of setting price" and "peruste" = "grounds" or "basis" or "reason".

Comment: English doesn't have compound words like that, but we could easily say "method of pricing", or even "pricing method", or just *pricing*. "The pricing for this item is based on weight"

Comment: @AndrewLeach Cool, "pricing method" is my favorite so far. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: "price-fixing" :the establishing of prices at a determined level, either by a government or by mutual consent among producers or sellers of a commodity. (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/price--fixing)

Comment: @mahmudkoya Price fixing refers to the practice of multiple vendors agreeing on (*fixing*) a price for something they sell. Depending on the market and the country, it may be illegal. The OP is looking for a term that means *pricing method*, which is quite different.

Comment: IMHO, you need a boolean "SoldByWeght" flag, not an "Unnamed" property whose values can be either "weight" or quantity". Alternatively, you could use "Units" and enter "each" as the unit for items sold by quantity.

Comment: You've probably named your API by now, and as @AndrewLeach suggests, *getPricingMethod* is good. You could also use *getPricingBasis* or *getPricingModel*, the latter being the one I would probably have settled on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with *pricing method* as suggested by Andrew Leach in the comments.